# How to compile (minimal static) Node.js (v0.12.1 and v0.12.2) on the RaspberryPi (ARM6) using Raspbian

Tags: node.js, arm, raspberry-pi, v8, raspbian

How to **compile Node.js v0.12.1** (and the most recent version, v0.12.2) on the RaspberryPi (ARM6) platform using **Raspbian**? If I download the source package from the Node.js website ([Node.js v0.12.1](http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.1/node-v0.12.1.tar.gz) or [Node.js v0.12.2](http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.2/node-v0.12.2.tar.gz)) and run the `./configure` script I'm getting this two errors:

- compilation fails with error messages on src/node.cc when I pass the `--without-ssl` option
- compilation is successfull, but when I execute `./node` in the `out/Release` directory I get the error of `Illegal instruction`

*So how to do it right?*

**Besides:** compiling a minimal static file. Researching the web does not lead to much information on this topic. So I tried it out by myself using this configuration command:

`./configure --without-npm --without-ssl --without-snapshot --fully-static`

The `--fully-static` option is self explaining and the other options are documented. Please note, that you need to patch `src/node.cc` if you are using `--without-ssl`.

**Resulting file sizes:**

- `./configure --without-npm --without-snapshot --fully-static` around **13 MB** (or 13565532 bytes)
- with `--without-ssl` around **10 MB** (10403783 bytes)

*If someone has ideas to reduce the resulting file size further I would be glad to read them in the comments.*

Answer (score 0):

*Info: if you are only interested in the solutions, you can omit text which is not written bold.*

It took me some days to figure out the problem(s) when compiling Node.js on the RaspberryPi. This might be related to the fact that it takes several hours to compile Node.js on the RaspberryPi. There are two major problems:

**1.) The compiling might not fail, but the resulting executeable will complain `Illegal instruction` if executed.** The reason for that is fairly simple: the binary is not compiled exactly for the the right ARM processor of the RaspberryPi and uses some CPU instruction not existing. This problem arises, because of a change of the properties in the file `/proc/cpuinfo` on Raspbian.

My `/proc/cpuinfo` file (using `2014-09-09-wheezy-raspbian`) looks like:

```
processor   : 0
model name  : ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l)
BogoMIPS    : 2.00
Features    : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp java tls 
...
```

In earlier versions the property `Processor` contained the string `ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l)`. In the file `deps/v8/src/base/cpu.cc` at line 380+ the `Processor` field is extracted. But this field contains now only a `0` and will lead to a wrong ARM architecture (`v7l` is assumed) assumption of the compiler and result in invalid instructions.

**To fix this problem: simply go to [the Gist I created here](https://gist.github.com/maxstrauch/101bd8047839a6fad88e) and get a fixed `cpu.cc` file. Replace the old file with this file. It simply reads out the `model name` field to get the right information.**

**2.) If you are using `--without-ssl` you will get the compiler error that `SSL2_ENABLE = true;` and `SSL3_ENABLE = true;` not exist.** I don't know exactly the source of the error since the two variables `SSL2_ENABLE` and `SSL3_ENABLE` are only used in lines 3000 and 3002 in `src/node.cc`. Furthermore the configuration script options `--enable-ssl2` and `--enable-ssl3` are not existing (see in `src/node.cc` lines 2999 and 3001).

**To fix this problem: download the [`node.cc` file from my Gist](https://gist.github.com/maxstrauch/101bd8047839a6fad88e#file-node-cc) and replace the old file with this file. Or comment out lines 3000 and 3002 by your self.**

**Another information: cloning the GIT repo of joynet/node will result in even more errors since some files have includes which are not satisfied yet (April 2nd of 2015). So in future times you might consider using the "older" versions v0.12.1 and v0.12.2, because they work.** I've only worked with v0.12.1 since v0.12.2 was released today.

*I hope this desert of text helps you.*